# Bluetooth mouse paired and connected but pointer not moving

Tags: bluetooth

Good Day!
I have a Bluetooth mouse paired and connected in Ubuntu 14.04 using the BlueDevil program, but pointer doesn't move and in Bluetooth devices list it shows type: unknown.(((((((
Maybe I need to change some setting files? Or manually tell Ubuntu that this is HID mouse? But i don't know how.(((((
Any help will be appreciated! See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEc6W.png)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I also have this problem. In my case simple restart of BT "solve" the problem.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

Comment: For those of you on systemd based systems do `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`.

Answer (score 0):

I Just had a similar issue with my microsoft bluetooth mouse 3600 so maybe my solution will work for you. My mouse worked fine for months, then I formatted and reinstalled ubuntu and it just refused to work. I tried switching my intel 7265 out for an 8260, I tried manually disconnecting and reconnecting the mouse from the command line with bluetoothctl. It would connect but the cursor wouldn't move.

Then I finally worked out I had to connect things in a specific order (I have a Logitech Bluetooth audio adapter). I disconnected everything, connected the **BT mouse first**, then connected the **Logitech BT audio adapter second**. Now everything works.